# Cannot authenticate with OAuth2

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, javascript, oauth2

I was testing an app and suddenly I can't login any more.
Neither my app or the Stack App configuration hasn't changed, so I'm thinking this might be a bug on the API side.

The OAuth error seems a bit off, as it tells me that the request is invalid and needs to be made over HTTPS:
[image]

[Here's a screencast (gif) of the issue](http://g.recordit.co/x4DWzG17LB.gif) that's also happening on [the docs page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib)

Anyone else encountered this issue?
It would've been great to have some sort of dedicated status page for Stack Apps, since there's nothing coming up on either https://twitter.com/StackStatus or https://stackstatus.net/

#### Update

This error seems to be happening intermittently. I'm seeing it again, and it surely is an issue on the api side:
[image]

What's the process for tracking bugs for stackexchange api?
Is posting a question here enough?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337298.

Comment: thanks for this! I’ll try it soon to see if it fixes my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an actual answer to the original issue, but it seems to be working fine now.

You can test by clicking on the button in the doc page: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib#login-button