# Error invalid_request "OAuth request must be over HTTPS" when starting oauth flow

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, oauth2

I'm building an application on top of StackExchange's API for a month now. While I was building the OAuth flow to allow users to authenticate using their StackExchange account, everything was working fine. Since a couple of days, though, the flow stopped working properly, and every time I try to connect I get an Application Login Failure:

```
error: invalid_request
error description: OAuth request must be over HTTPS
```

I'm using https://github.com/acruxray/passport-stack-exchange/ to handle the OAuth flow.

I'm I missing something or is this an error on the API itself?

How could it be working before but not anymore?

Comment: Welcome! You might be facing the same issue as [this user](https://stackapps.com/q/8454/34061).

Comment: It does seem like it, indeed. Thanks for pointing it out.